# How to draw a circle inside a square in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: circle inside a square]

I would to draw this image in latex but how do I change the middle diagram to a circle or a square but with the same labeling.

And also replicate the extrapolation diagram.

[image: extrapolation]

Comment: You are asking two completely different questions here... Please separate them and show some more effort. What have you tried? Where exactly did you get stuck? Also have a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi Abby, thanks but I have no idea how to go about this that's why I asked. I would have definitely posted what I tried like my previous questions if I had an idea how to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First part: the circle inside a square

[image: cirle in square v01]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node(square) [minimum size=6cm, draw=lightgray, fill=gray!25!white] at (0,0) {} node[above right=60pt] {$\Omega^+$};
        \node(circle) [circle, inner sep=1.5cm, draw=blue!50!black, fill=white] at (0,0) {$\Omega^-$};
        
        \draw[-latex] ($ (square.west) + (-1,1) $)  node[anchor=east] {$\partial \Omega$} -- ($ (square.west) + (0,1) $);
        \draw[-latex] ($ (square.west) + (-1,0) $)  node[anchor=east] {$\Gamma$} -- (circle.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Second part: Interpolation

For interpolation,  used [this online tool](https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/) to get the coordinates of the points, did a fit and calculated the `intersections` of the vertical lines and the functions.

[image: interpolation v01]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\strut}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        % lines and labels
        
        \foreach \x/\labb [count=\i from 1] in {0/$\tilde{u}(-2\Delta x)$, 3/$\tilde{u}(-\Delta x)$, 6/$\tilde{u}(0)$, 8/$\tilde{u}(x_i-x_l)$, 9/, 12/}{
            \draw[name path=p-\i, draw=lightgray] (\x,1) node (la-\i) {} -- (\x,5) node (lb-\i) {};
            \node[above=5pt] at (lb-\i) {\labb};
        }
    
        \foreach \y in {1,...,5}{
            \draw[draw=lightgray] (0,\y) node (lc-\y) {} -- (12,\y);
        }
        
        \draw[draw=blue, fill=cyan] (la-1) circle[radius=2.5pt] node[below=5pt] {$u_{i-2}$};
        \draw[draw=blue, fill=cyan] (la-2) circle[radius=2.5pt] node[below=5pt] {$u_{i-1}$};
        \filldraw[blue] (la-3) circle[radius=2.5pt] node[below=5pt] {$u_i$};
        \filldraw[red] (la-4) circle[radius=2.5pt] node[below=5pt] {$u_l$};
        \draw[draw=gray, fill=lightgray] (la-5) circle[radius=2.5pt] node[below=5pt] {$u_{i+1}^G$};
        \draw[draw=gray, fill=lightgray] (la-6) circle[radius=2.5pt] node[below=5pt] {$u_{i+2}^G$};
        \draw[blue] (la-1) -- (la-2) -- (la-3);
        \draw[blue] (la-4) -- (la-5) -- (la-6);
        \draw[red] (la-3) -- (la-4);
        
        \node[anchor=east] at ($ (lc-1)!0.5!(lc-2) $) {Constant};
        \node[anchor=east] at ($ (lc-2)!0.5!(lc-3) $) {Linear};
        \node[anchor=east] at ($ (lc-3)!0.5!(lc-4) $) {Quadratic};
        \node[anchor=east] at ($ (lc-4)!0.5!(lc-5) $) {Cubic};
        
        % functions and dots
        
        \draw[name path=f-1, domain=0:12, smooth, variable=\x, green!50!black] plot ({\x}, {-0.002*\x^3 + 0.0268*\x^2 - 0.082*\x + 4.7259});
        \draw[name path=f-2, domain=2.999:12.001, smooth, variable=\x, green!50!black] plot ({\x}, {-0.022*\x^2 + 0.2694*\x + 2.9558
        });
        \filldraw[lightgray] (0,3.691) circle [radius=2.5pt];
        \draw[name path=f-3, domain=5.999:12.001, smooth, variable=\x, green!50!black] plot ({\x}, {-0.0391*\x + 2.763});
        \filldraw[lightgray] (0,2.412) circle [radius=2.5pt];
        \filldraw[lightgray] (3,2.301) circle [radius=2.5pt];
        \draw[name path=f-4, domain=7.999:12.001, smooth, variable=\x, green!50!black] plot ({\x}, {1.75});
        \filldraw[lightgray] (0,1.728) circle [radius=2.5pt];
        \filldraw[lightgray] (3,1.603) circle [radius=2.5pt];
        \filldraw[lightgray] (6,1.824) circle [radius=2.5pt];
        
        % intersections
        
        \foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
            \path[name intersections={of=f-1 and p-\i,by=P-\i}];
            \filldraw[green!50!black] (P-\i) circle[radius=2.5pt];
        }
        \foreach \i in {2,...,6}{
            \path[name intersections={of=f-2 and p-\i,by=P-\i}];
            \filldraw[green!50!black] (P-\i) circle[radius=2.5pt];
        }
        \foreach \i in {3,...,6}{
            \path[name intersections={of=f-3 and p-\i,by=P-\i}];
            \filldraw[green!50!black] (P-\i) circle[radius=2.5pt];
        }
        \foreach \i in {4,...,6}{
            \path[name intersections={of=f-4 and p-\i,by=P-\i}];
            \filldraw[green!50!black] (P-\i) circle[radius=2.5pt];
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @user3307971 I edited your question. have a look, if it suits your need...

Comment: @user3307971 next time, it would be better to post two seperate questions in case the content is not related.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @Excelsior